# File download from FTPS folder via HTTPS Protocol

Tags: c#, https, ftps

I have an activeX Control which is downloading some files from an FTPS server.
Now I want to change the protocol to HTTPS .

Is there some way to access an ftp folder like `https://192.0.0.0/filename.xml` where `192.0.0.0` is the ftp host name?

Comment: FTP, FTPS, and HTTPS are all different protocols, run of different ports and have different services that handle them.  While it is possible to access same data with different protocols, it would have to be set up that way by the sys admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many HTTP proxy servers let you request FTP resource via them. So if you can route the request to the proxy, you can ask it to retrieve the file from FTP URL for you. Otherwise no, you would have to run (and properly configure) an HTTP server on the system where the file resides.